# Visual Studio 2010 $(PlatformName) macro incompatible with MSBuild.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, pre-build-event

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 with this in the pre-build event command line:

```
echo "$(Configuration)" - "$(PlatformName)" - "$(Platform)"
exit 1
```

and the results are:

```
"Debug" - "AnyCPU" - "AnyCPU"
```

even though the macro section of that window suggests that `PlatformName` should appear as `Any CPU` in this case (with a space): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzplE.png (even though MSDN seems to suggest that there is no space at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

```
msbuild /property:Configuration="Debug" /property:Platform="AnyCPU"
1>MyProgram.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|AnyCPU" is invalid.
```

What's going on here? Unfortunately, `"AnyCPU"` is not a valid platform on the command line, so I am unable to proceed. The above works just fine with `/property:Platform="Any CPU"` (with a space).

Is there another macro I can use, or some flag for MSBuild to accept the platform anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've hit [MSBuild bug 503935](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503935/msbuild-inconsistent-platform-for-any-cpu-between-solution-and-project):

### Report:

> The msbuild Platform property has a different value for Any CPU
>   depending upon whether you are building the solution or building a
>   project.
>
> Solution use Platform="Any CPU" - space
>
> Project use Platform="AnyCPU" - no space

### Response:

> Posted by Microsoft on 11/2/2009 at 7:22 PM
>
> Thanks for taking the time to send us your feedback.
>
> Unfortunatley, having just shipped Beta 2, it is too late in the cycle
>   to make adjustments at this point. It makes perfect sense that we
>   should make these two the same. Looks like we should use "AnyCPU"
>   consistently for both. We also need to make sure that we are backward
>   compatible, so we will have to take this in consideration.
>
> In the next round, we hope to be doing work around the solution, and
>   we can perhaps fix this during that cycle. For this cycle, I am
>   resolving this bug as "Won't Fix".
>
> Thanks,
>
> Chuck England
>
> Visual Studio Platform Program Manager - MSBuild

### Final Resolution:

> Closed as Won't Fix

Comment: Hmm, guess that's it then. An `if` statement in a batch file takes care of it for the time being.